# Using typescript instanceof guards on array elements?

Tags: typescript

Working on some very basic Typescript examples for educational purposes, I came up with a super-class called `Note` with a subclass called `Todo`. The `Todo` class contains a `toggleComplete()` method that the `Note` class lacks. I then used the following code to create an intentional error:

```
let notes:Note[] = [];
notes[0] = new Note("Note content");
notes[1] = new Todo("Todo content");

console.log(notes[1].toggleComplete()); // error. Note objects do not contain toggleComplete()
```

This is all well and good and my students understood why it didn't work. Then I tried to show them how to use an instanceof guard to solve the problem and I tried this:

```
if (notes[1] instanceof Todo) {
    notes[1].toggleComplete(); // Same error! Why?
}
```

If I assign `notes[1]` to another variable first, it works fine:

```
let n = notes[1];
if (n instanceof Todo) {
   console.log(n.toggleComplete();) //no error, as expected
}
```

But that feels like an unnecessary workaround, and would not extend well to a traditional index-based `for` loop (yes, I know I could use a `for of` loop but I'm avoiding those for now for reasons beyond the scope of this post). Is there a way to get Typescript to recognize instanceof guards on individual array elements?

Comment: Looks like this is a [longstanding, still open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  Your workaround is how I'd suggest dealing with it.

Comment: Thanks! I searched for an issue but didn't find that one. Apparently I had the wrong search terms.